# Custom regex pattern for matching email addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have content that I am reading in that I need to collect the emails from within. However, I just want to pull the email that comes after From:

Here is an example:

```
Recip: fhavor@gmail.com
Subject: Report results (Gd)
Headers: Received: from daem.com (unknown [127.1.1.1])
Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 13:11:42 +0000 (GMT)
From: Tavon Lo <lt35@gmail.com>
```

As you can see there are multiple emails but I want to only collect the email that comes after the From: part of the content.Which would be "lt35@gmail.com". So far I have a good regex that collects ALL the emails within the content.

```
   EMAIL = r"((?:^|\b)(?:[^\s]+?\@(?:.+?)\[\.\][a-zA-Z]+)(?:$|\b))"
```

I am new to regex patterns so any ideas or suggestions as to how to improve the above pattern to only collect the emails that come after from: would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?m)^From:[^<>\n\r]*<([^<>@]+@[^<>]+)>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvgI8f/1).

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - `re.M` inline modifier option
- `^` - start of a line
- `From:` - a literal string
- `[^<>\n\r]*` - zero or more chars other than `<`, `>`, CR and LF
- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>@]+@[^<>]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `@`, then a `@` char and then one or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

See a Python demo:

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^From:[^<>\n\r]*<([^<>@]+@[^<>]+)>', re.M) # Define the regex

with open(your_file_path, 'r') as f:  # Open file for reading
  print(rx.findall(f.read()))         # Get all the emails after From:
```

Comment: This does work. Question- if i wanted to include "sender:" how would i implement that. So it gets the email if it starts with "from:" or "sender:"?  Would it go something like this - (?m)^From:|Sender:[^<>\n\r]*<([^<>@]+@[^<>]+)>

Comment: @CoderGuru See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvgI8f/2).

Comment: Quick question- What if after sender there is no name (Tavon Lo). It is just Sender: something@gmail.com.I tried (?m)^Sender:[^<>\n\r]*([^<>@]+@[^<>]+) but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: @CoderGuru Sorry, I do not quite get it, what you are doing. Maybe `(?m)^Sender:[^\S\n\r]*([^\s@]+@\S+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvgI8f/3).

Comment: That is exaclty is. Now is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: @CoderGuru Maybe like `(?m)^Sender:[^\S\n\r]*(?:[^\r\n<]*<)?([^\s@]+@[^>\s]+)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvgI8f/4).